# Setup has detected that visual studio 2015 update 3 may not be completely installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I try to update VS 2015 Update 3 from Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Updates window and click Modify it doesn't show VS 2015 Update 3 as in the picture.

[image: Picture]

However, when I download it from www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs and open the file (called vs2015.3) it shows me this time the Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 but not clickable way as in the picture. What can I solve this issue?

[image: Picture]

Comment: how can you tell that you are not already on update 3?

Comment: Same question as @AmrAlaa: did you check the current VS version? Help => About Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If your purpose is to install the `.Net` core and it was giving an error saying that you haven't installed VS Update 3 properly, then you can solve it by running :

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

Take a look [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/6067207.aspx) and also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites#issues) for where I got my sources.