# "Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 may not be completely installed...."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

> "...Please repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, then install this
>   product again."

I'm getting this when I try and update the ASP.NET Web Tools Extension in my version of VS 2015 which I installed only today. After I got this error I checked and my version was Update 3. I tried to install it regardless and got a message saying that I already had it.

Any ideas on how I can get around this issue?

Comment: I am thinking the most likely fix will be uninstalling Visual Studio entirely and then re-installing.  I'm having the same issue and haven't found any other fix yet.

Comment: @DavidCram see answer below

Comment: That's awesome.  I can't wait to get home and try it for myself.  Thanks for posting your solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup has detected that visual studio 2015 update 3 may not be completely installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684594/setup-has-detected-that-visual-studio-2015-update-3-may-not-be-completely-instal)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ok after some digging I got to the bottom of this. It seems that I need to have .Net Core Installed. However when I go to install that I get the same error. The workaround is to run the downloaded .exe from the command line with the added parameter:

> DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1

This will install the latest version of Web Tools as well.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of downloading it from VisualStudio tools update tab, just go to http://www.asp.net/core and download the latest dev tools DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.1.exe.

Installed perfectly for me.