# Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools VS2015 update tool won't detect Visual Studio 2015 although it is installed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to update Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools in Visual Studio 2015, but I get the following error:

"This product requires Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 or later. Please install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 or later, then install this product again."

However, I do have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 installed. I think this error may be related to the fact that there are several versions of Visual Studio installed in this computer (2008, 2010, 2015, 2017).

How can I make sure the update tool recognizes the correct installed version?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to install the .Net core and it was giving an error saying that you haven't installed VS Update 3 properly, then you can solve it by running :

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

[Source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684594/setup-has-detected-that-visual-studio-2015-update-3-may-not-be-completely-instal)